# Как включить подсказки для языка PHP в редакторе для кода "Brackets"?

Tags: php, brackets

Здравствуйте. Начал писать код PHP в  "*Brackets*" и у меня не появляются подсказки на переменные и другое как с *JS*, *CSS*, *HTML*. Возможно ли подключить на этом редакторе подсказки для PHP?

Comment: Сам пользуюсь PHP SmartHints ..